# How to tie comments with postid to the post with that postid?

Tags: php, post, get

This is a real struggle. I've been trying to debug for the better part of 1 hour, but I can't find any solution. I'm making a comment system that ties to a blog post. When you post a comment, you're returned to the same post. The post page is filled dynamically based on postid. The comments are added using the same postid so they populate only their relevant post. My query to lookup comments is wrong, but I don't get how.

```
Warning
: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\prog1\comments.php on line 31
```

Code:

```
<?php
require("connect.php");
$postid = $_GET['id'];

if(isset($_POST['postcomment'])){
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $author = $_SESSION['username'];
    $commentQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO comments (com_content, com_timestamp, com_author, com_postid) VALUES ('$comment', now(), '$author', '$postid')");
    if($commentQuery){
        header('Location: postpage.php?id='.$postid);  
    }


}
?>

<div class="comments-separator">
</div>
<div class="flex-enable comments-wrapper flex-column">
<span class="comment-header">Comments</span>
    <div class="comment-new-wrapper">
        <form class="flex-enable flex-column" method="POST">
            <textarea class="blog-input-text comment-entry" cols="40" rows="3" name="comment"></textarea>
            <input class="comment-button small-white-subtitle" type="submit" name="postcomment" value="Post Comment">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    $summonComm = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE com_postid='".$postid."' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $resultComm = mysqli_query($conn, $summonComm);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultComm)){
        $comment= $row['com_content'];
        $timestamp= $row['timestamp'];
        $author= $row['com_author'];
    ?>
    <span class="blog-timestamp"><?php echo $timestamp; ?> • Written by <a href="<?php echo $author; ?>.php"><?php echo $author; ?></a></span>
    <span class="blog-entry"><?php echo $comment; ?></span>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: So what is it doing wrong ?

Comment: _Small point_ You need and `exit;` after the `header()` as header does not stop execution of the current script, it just sends a header to the browser

Comment: Added my error.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: you should try running your SQL at the command line and observing the results.

none of my business, but you're not doing anything by way of filtering or validating input or escaping output and that's really not good.

Comment: You have most probably an error in your SELECT. But I can not see it.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY id DESC` does not work because my db field is called "com_postid".
`$timestamp = $row['timestamp']` doesn't work because my db field is called "com_timestamp".